# Is there any numpy function that can make small in terms of column diagonal matrices with big amount of elements in rows?

Tags: python, numpy

I need to create the numpy array of the shape Nx2N. This should be like a stack of diagonal matrices win n zeros and ones in the rows

`[1100 [111000
 0011  000111
 1100  111000
 0011] 000111
       111000
       000111]`

I've tried to create arrays of ones and zeros and concatenate them. But instead of matrix got another big array

```py
N=4
ones = np.ones(N)
zeros = np.zeros(N)
odd_row = np.concatenate([ones,zeros])
even_row = np.concatenate([zeros,ones])
two_row = np.concatenate((odd_row, even_row), axis=0)
a = np.empty(0)
total = a
for i in range (0, N//2):
    total = np.concatenate((total, two_row), axis=0)
total = total.reshape(N, 2*N)
```

Comment: can you add an expected output ?

Comment: the output should be the matrix size of N * 2N and the examples for N=2 and N=3 are in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with using a range that you convert to 1's and 0s before reshaping it

```
N = 3
r = np.arange(N*N*2)//N
r = np.reshape(1 - r%2 ^ r//2%2,(N,2*N))

[[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
 [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]]
```

The way it works is by preparing all the values in a single array of the appropriate length and reshaping it at the end.

The values are produced from a range using the following numerical properties:

- Considering left and right blocks as "column numbers", the block column numbers will be i//N % 2
- Each row number will be i//(2*N)
- even vs odd row numbers are identified with i//(2*N)%2
- To alternate 1s and 0s, we use an exclusive or `^` between the even-odd values (0 or 1) of rows and the block column values (also 0 or 1)
- To get the 1s block first, we subtract the result from 1 which inverses the 1s and 0s
- Finally we reshape the array into a matrix

Visually, (for N=3) this is what the intermediate values will look like:

```
r (range)  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17]

r//N       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5]
r//N//2    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]

r//N%2     [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
r//N//2%2  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

^          [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
1 - .      [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]

reshape    [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0][0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1][1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
```

You could also process the rows and columns patterns separately and combine them into a matrix (rather than use reshape):

```
 r = np.arange(1,N+1)[:,None]%2 ^ np.arange(N*2)//N
```

This makes the 1s and 0s patterns a bit more straightforward.

A more "mechanical" way to do it is to prepare a two row matrix with the even and odd lines and then use alternating 0 and 1 indexes to form the actual rows of the matrix:

```
zo   = np.arange(2*N)//N    # [0,0,0,1,1,1]
ozzo = np.array([1-zo,zo])  # [[1,1,1,0,0,0][0,0,0,1,1,1]] odd/even rows
r = ozzo[np.arange(N)%2]    # ozzo[0,1,0,1,0,1] actual row selection
```

Comment: oh this is way more clear than previous answer, thanks! :)

Comment: it's seems that it's not in the right order, like there zeros first in first row and it should be ones first like 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0

Comment: Right.   didn't notice that, simply subtract the result from 1,  I fixed the answer

Comment: _"This solution runs 2 to 3 times faster than the other proposed approach."_ True only for very small toy examples. Aready at `N=20` it is actually significantly slower. At `N=100` your _"even faster"_ solution is four times slower than my original one. And the factor further increases with N.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one method using broadcasting:

```
n = 5

sum(np.ogrid[:n*n:n,-n:n])//n&1
```

or (more typing but faster)

```
np.arange(n)[:,None]+np.arange(-n,n)//n)&1
```

or (different strategy even more typing but faster)

```
def f_pp():
    out = np.zeros((n,2*n),int)
    flat = out.ravel()               
    flat[3*n:-n].reshape(-1,2*n)[::2] = 1 
    flat[:n] = 1
    if not n&1:
        flat.ravel()[-n:] = 1
    return out


# array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
#        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
#        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

`ogrid` creates

```
c,r = np.ogrid[:n*n:n,-n:n]
```

a column

```
array([[ 0],
       [ 5],
       [10],
       [15],
       [20]])
```

and a row

```
array([[-5, -4, -3, -2, -1,  0,  1,  2,  3, 4]])
```

These are chosen such that they can easily be transformed into binary patterns:

```
c//n&1

array([[0],
       [1],
       [0],
       [1],
       [0]])

r//n&1

array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

which are then summed leveraging broadcasting and the lsbit kept.

Comment: Thank you for adding the detailed explanation! Now it's more understandable